# How do I disable Pycharm's new pytest debugging configuration?

Tags: pycharm

Typically, I define a main method and use a normal debugger to perform test-driven-development in pycharm:

```
def test_foo():
   return

def main():
   test_foo()

if __name__ == "__main__":
   main()
   # and I can allow or comment out pytest
   pytest.main([__file__, '-s'])
```

And run in external scope (CLI, terminal, CI/CD) with `pytest`.

This has worked great because I have full control of the debugging process and nothing is different than when I run a normal code.

---

One problem: the latest `pycharm` version now detects that the file is a unit-test file, and forks the debugging configuration over to some sort of `pytest` driven runtime that ignores any main method machinery I've set up.

Now, I have to go through some research curve where I find the buttons, then discover the ritual necessary to toggle or modify this new feature s.t. I still walk through my main method (where some additional things happen, such as more manual testing and visualization).

Before embarking on that journey, is there a straightforward way to generate a debug configuration for a unit test file in the **latest pycharm version** (2021.2.3)?

> Also, and this seems to be unintended behavior: the pathing is incorrect when running in the new default configuration.  Test paths (in my code) are reasonably configured relative to the project root.  These paths used to work in the default debug configuration, but they now fail in this new pytest closure. The working directory now defaults to the location of the test script rather than the project root.

Comment: It would be useful to clarify what button / command you're using whose behaviour has changed; I'm guessing the "Run" button on the main toolbar? Also, you could try asking JetBrains support directly - click Help -> Contact Support in the menu bar.

Comment: @IMSoP right click on the open code tab, select "debug"; I'll try manually creating a debug configuration instead.   I'll also try pinging them.